# Send data to Bluetooth module when a notification or call is received

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently writing an app and would like some advice on best practices.

The idea of the app is to open it up, scan for and then select a bluetooth device (this is BLE by the way) and connect to it. I'd then like to send a command via Bluetooth every time a notification or call is received (this would be done in the background).

I've got the scanning and connecting part working and know I can use the notificationlistenerservice and phonestatelistener (or similar) for detecting the calls & notifications. These will both be set up as individual services. I can also manually send serial data to the bluetooth module via the main activity.

What I'd like advice on is the best way to maintain a connection to the Bluetooth module and send it specific commands (serial data) when a notification/call is received. Should I run a service for maintaining a connection to the module or should I duplicate the code for each service and connect to the module each time I want to send data to it? If I have a background service for the Bluetooth connection I would want the activity and call/notification services to be able to call methods on it to then send the required data to the module.

Hopefully this makes sense and thanks in advance.